# WinRT 8.1 Settings Charm using Caliburn.Micro: how to remove a command from settings?

Tags: windows-runtime, settings, caliburn.micro

I've faced the problem of deleting a command from settings charm.
The problem is a user should only see the Sign Out command when he is logged in the app but not on the login screen.

For now being I've not found any suitable way to remove a command or clear the whole list of commands and add all besides the Sign Out command.

To manage with settings commands Caliburn.Micro is used.

```
private WinRTContainer _container;
........
        private void RegisterSettingsCommands(bool isSignedIn)
    {
#if WINDOWS_APP
        var settings = _container.RegisterSettingsService();
        if (!isSignedIn)
        {
            settings.RegisterCommand(new Components.ActionSettingsCommand("Settings", () => { }));
            settings.RegisterCommand(new Components.ActionSettingsCommand("Contact Us About a Problem", () => { }));
            settings.RegisterCommand(new Components.ActionSettingsCommand("Support Information", () => { }));
            settings.RegisterCommand(new Components.ActionSettingsCommand("Tutorial", () => { }));
            settings.RegisterCommand(new Components.ActionSettingsCommand("Submit Product Feedback", () => { }));
            settings.RegisterFlyoutCommand<AboutViewModel>("About");
        }
        else
        {
            settings.RegisterCommand(new Components.ActionSettingsCommand(
                "Sign Out", HandleSignOutCommand));
        }
#endif
    }
```

So, just to conclude I need the following logic:

-when a user is on the login screen he doesn't see the Sign Out command;

-when the user is logged in the Sign Out command appears;

-when the user logs out the Sign Out command should be removed from the settings commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in CM 2.0.0 yet.